# redirdev device support live migration?

Tags: usb, qemu

I am tyring to do live migration with redirdev usb device,
there is redirdev usb device define in source,
but the usb device will be absent in target vm after migration until I perform attach-device:

$ virsh attach-device usb --file usbredir.xml  --current

```
<redirdev bus='usb' type='tcp'>
  <source mode='connect' host='70.182.132.218' service='12345'/>
  <protocol type='raw'/>
  <address type='usb' bus='0' port='2'/>
</redirdev>
```

It seems the target qemu has loss the connection with usbredirserver?